# How to setup Netdata to monitor my website performance?

Tags: network-monitoring, netdata

So I have installed netdata on my machine using this tutorial https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-install-netdata-on-windows-10-wsl.html

I started it in my browser via the provided command `127.0.0.1:19999` and it only monitors and sends performance of my local machine (the laptop I'm using)

I own a website so I tried to enter my website IP + 19999 at the end but of course that did not work.

I'd like to set it up so I can measure live performance from my website.
Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your website runs on a server that your hosting provider owns. To use Netdata, Netdata would have to already be installed on your provider's hosting infrastructure, or you would require sufficient (effectively administrator) access to your hosting server (or servers) to install it yourself, which many hosting services would be unlikely to provide. If you are using a hosting provider that manages your website hosting you likely don't need Netdata to monitor your website performance - monitoring then is considered to be part of what you pay for.

On the other hand, if you are managing your own cloud infrastructure, it should be easy (and a good idea) to install Netdata to monitor any website servers that run on top of it.